# Migration of Universal Analytics to GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, analytics.js

I have transitioned from Universal Analytics (UA) to GA4 using the assistant.

1. If UA stops collecting data, is it likely that GA4 will also stop collecting data?
2. Is it possible to reuse the analytics.js code and keep the old keys in it? I hesitate to say this, but I prefer not to update the code and would rather reuse the old code. (Will this have an impact when data collection ceases?)"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl43W.png)

With the assistant, GA4 is being used for data collection, and everything is working as anticipated unless UA ceases data collection on July 1, 2023

Comment: ga4 is completely different than ua.  you can't reuse the code

Comment: code in the image is about Ads not Analytics...